# Как присвоить StatusBar текст выделенной строки в CheckBox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

У меня на форме есть `CheckBox`. Нажимаю на какую нибудь строку и она выделяется.  После того, как я выбрал строку её имя должно перенестись в `StatusBar`.

```
 StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Form1.CheckListBox1.Items.Text;
```

Пробовал так, но в панель кидается весь текст из `CheckBox`.

Comment: Подробности в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но будет выводить текст только последнего выбранного элемента (даже если чекнуто много).

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := CheckListBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex];
end;
```

Чтобы все выбранные выводить можно так:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := '';

  for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Count - 1 do
      begin
          if (CheckListBox1.Checked[i]) then
              StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text + ' ' + CheckListBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[i];
      end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обратиться к выделенному элементу.
Для этого используем *CheckListBox1.ItemIndex*

```
if CheckListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then  
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Form1.CheckListBox1.Items[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex].Text;
```